# File exists warning on live server

Tags: php

### Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in /home/content/xx/xxxxxxxx/html/xxxx/xxxx/action.php on line xx

This warning is on live server. But in localhost there is no warning.

I am trying :

```
if(!file_exists($path)){
   mkdir($path);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first check your `$path`. Is it a directory location?

If it is, you wanted to check a directory is exists or not so

Use:

```
if(!is_dir($path)){
   mkdir($path);
}
```

If directory is not created.

Check is there your directory create permission!

Comment: Nothing new happened!

Comment: I have posted warning on heading!

Comment: may be $path variable is not containing a directory location. will you sure printing it